# Perl - How to handle huge files for searching similar words

Tags: perl, grep, filehandle

I'm working with huge files. I would like to know, in your opinion, what is the best way to handle huge files when you would like to know if the word "x" in $file1, is present in the sentence "y" in file2. 
My files have more than 20000 lines..

Example:

This is the content of the first file :

```
eat
take
breath
you
alpha
```

This is the content of the second file :

```
eat,hungry
love,lovers
me,mine
take,taken,give
you,u,yo
fun,funny
```

This is the content that I might expect for the third file

```
eat : eat,hungry
take : take,taken,give
you : you,u,yo
```

So as you can see, I would like to find the matching expression in the second file of the word of the first file.

My solutions - but the loop never ends -

solution1:

```
$file1= "words.txt";
$file2 = "expressions.txt";
$out = "out.txt";

open (W, "<", $file1);
open (E, "<", $file2);
open (OUT, ">", $out);

while(defined($l = <W>)){
    @a = split (/\n/, $l);
    push @w, @a;
}

while(defined($l2 = <E>)){
    for ($i = 0; $i < @w; $i++){
        if (grep /\Q\b$w[$i]\b\E/, $l2){ #or just /\b$w[$i]\b/
            print OUT "$w[$i] : $l2\n";
        }
    }
}
```

solution2:

```
$file1= "words.txt";
$file2 = "expressions.txt";
$out = "out.txt";

open (W, "<", $file1);
open (E, "<", $file2);
open (OUT, ">", $out);

while(defined($l = <W>)){
    @a = split (/\n/, $l);
    push @w, @a;

while(defined($l2 = <E>)){
    @b = split (/\n/, $l2);
    push @e, @b;
}

for ($k = 0; $k < @e; $k++){
    for ($i = 0; $i < @w; $i++){
        if (grep /\b$w[$i]\b/, $e[$k]){
            print OUT "$w[$i] : $w[$l]\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sidenote, `$l2 =~ /\Q\b$w[$i]\b\E/` is better than `grep /\Q\b$w[$i]\b\E/, $l2` and if you want to match word boundary and NOT literal `\b` then `/\b\Q$w[$i]\E\b/`

Comment: Ok I edited. However, why is better the first expression ?

Comment: `$l2 =~ ..` is better as it better communicates intention, which is to match regex against single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about process the expression file first to make a dictionary map every word to a sentence, then find if the word in words.txt is in the dictionary? I guess this may be faster. Source code is as below:

```
#! /opt/VRTSperl/bin/perl

    $words = "words.txt";
    $expressions = "expressions.txt";
    $out = "out.txt";

    open (E, "<", $expressions);
    open (W, "<", $words);
    open (OUT, ">", $out);

    my %dic;

    while (my $sentence = <E>) {
        chomp($sentence);
        my @words = split(/,/, $sentence);
        foreach my $word (@words) {
            $dic{$word} .= "$sentence";
        }   
    }

    while (my $word = <W>) {
        chomp($word);
        if ($dic{$word}) {
            print OUT "$word : $dic{$word}\n"
        }   
    }
```

Comment: really? in my side, the out file is

eat : eat,hungry
take : take,taken,give
you : you,u,yo

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
open (my $fh, "<", "f1.txt") or die $!;
open (my $fh2, "<", "f2.txt") or die $!;
my @keys;
while(chomp(my $line = <$fh>)){
        push @keys, $line;
}
while(chomp(my $line2 = <$fh2>)){
        foreach (@keys){
                if ($line2 =~ $_){
                        print "$_ : $line2\n";
                }
        }
}
```

Output

```
eat : eat,hungry
take : take,taken,give
you : you,u,yo
```

Comment: will it work if, for ex., the word is in the middle? for ex. the word is "a", and the expression is "c,a,b".

Comment: after 10 min is still running . However I've already noticed some errors -> continue : continuellement, constamment

Comment: Sorry I don't get it, please rephrase your question by editing it, I'd be happy to help.

Comment: sorry! for ex. in file 1 there is the word "continue", in file 2 there is "continuellement, constamment"... So it seems that for it "continue" is the same of "continuellement" so I think it doesn't recognized the right word. The other question is : if the word "continue" is in the middle of the expression of file 2 (so for ex. "continuellement, CONTINUE, continuel" I think your code doesn't work. Did I explain better the question?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to match literal `\b` instead of word boundary, so

```
/\Q\b$w[$i]\b\E/
```

should actually be

```
/\b\Q$w[$i]\E\b/
```